# Dataframe Dealing With Missing Time Series Data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My DataFrame is an array time series taken every minute over a period of ~60 days.

1. First I want to segment the df into 24 hour periods.
2. Then I want to plot certain attributes as a waterfall chart, line graphs on top of each other.

I'm thinking of using `iloc` in a `for` loop to do this as the df rows are indexed by time, meaning there are 3600 rows per day. The problem is that I don't know how to assign each to a variable.

```
for i in range(58)
     df = timethingdf.iloc[809+i*3600:809+(i+1)*3600]
```

As you can see, I would like `df` to be different for each of the 58 dfs I am making with this.

And I have no idea on how to do the chart.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should've meant this:

```
for i in range(58)
    df = timethingdf.iloc[809+i*3600:809+(i+1)*3600]
    # Doing something with `df`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `TimeGrouper`:

```
data = {'date':['2004-1-2:10:10:00', '2004-1-2:10:11:00', '2004-1-1:11:11:00', '2004-1-1:11:13:00'], 'foo':[5,6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S')
df = df.set_index('date')
grouped = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('24H')).sum()

In [7]: grouped
Out[8]:
            foo
date
2004-01-01   15
2004-01-02   11
```

You can then replace `.sum()` with whatever aggregator you want to use on the grouped subsets.